# Is a CDN an appropriate solution to cache query results?

Tags: ajax, caching, scalability, cdn

I'm working on a little search engine, where I'm trying to find out how to cache query results.
These results are simple JSON text, retrieved using an ajax request.

Storing results in memory is not an option, I can see two options remaining:

- Use a nosql database to retrieve cached results.
- Store results on a CDN and redirect the http request (307 - Temporary Redirect) in case the result was already cached.

However, I don't have much experience with CDN, and wonder if using it for a huge amount of temporary small text files is a good practice.
Is it a good practice to use redirection on an ajax request?
Is a CDN an appropriate solution to cache small text files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: no.

Long: Usually, you use a CDN for large static files that you want the CDN to mirror all around the world so it's close to a user when she requests them. When you have data that changes a lot, it would always take a while to propagate the changes to all nodes of the CDN, in the meantime users get inconsistent results (this may or may not matter to you).

Also, to avoid higher latency I wouldn't use an HTTP redirect (where you tell the client to make a second request to somewhere else) but rather figure out whether to get the data from the cache or the engine on your end (e.g. using a [caching proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server#Caching) or a load balancer) and then serve it directly to the client.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! What if I'd like to cache results for two days, setting the cache-control header, would a regular CDN behave as expected? If this is the case, wouldn't the CDN high availability bring a good balance with the redirect cost?